# Javafx: TreeView adding items with right order

Tags: javafx

i asked this question before but did'nt get any response! [Javafx: Adjusting TreeView with right order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779079/javafx-adjusting-treeview-with-right-order). Please i need help to solve this problem. here is code

```
public class Main extends Application
{       public static void main(String[] args)
            {launch(args);}

    static final Map<TreeItem<String>, BorderPane> map = new HashMap();
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {        
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        TreeItem<String> tree = new TreeItem<String>("Main System");
        TreeItem<String> item1 = new TreeItem<String>("Roots");
        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<String>(tree); 
        treeView.setOnMouseClicked((event)->{
           TreeItem<String> TreeItem = (TreeItem<String>)treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
           if(TreeItem.getValue().equals("Roots"))
            {              
               root.setCenter(getRootsPanel());
            }
           else
            {
               root.setCenter(map.get(TreeItem));
            }
        });

        treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<String>,TreeCell<String>>(){
            @Override
            public TreeCell<String> call(TreeView<String> p) {
                return new AddMenuTreeCell();
            }
        });
        tree.setExpanded(true);
        root.setLeft(treeView);
        tree.getChildren().add(item1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 500);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tree View");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

   TreeItem<String> addNewTreeItem(String name){ 
       TreeItem TreeItem = new TreeItem(name);
       return TreeItem;
    } 
   private static class AddMenuTreeCell extends TextFieldTreeCell<String> {
        private ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();            
        private TextField textField;

        public AddMenuTreeCell() {
            MenuItem newitem1 = new MenuItem("Insert Roots");
            MenuItem newitem2 = new MenuItem("Insert Coordinates");
            menu.getItems().addAll(newitem1,newitem2);
            newitem1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {              
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {                      
                    TreeItem<String> item3 = new TreeItem<String>("Roots");
                       //     item3.getChildren().clear();
                            getTreeItem().getChildren().add(item3);            
                }    
            });   
            newitem2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    TreeItem<String> newLeaf =  new TreeItem<String>("Coordinates");
                                TreeItem<String> uxItem1 = new TreeItem("X");
                                map.put(uxItem1, getrightPane1());
                                TreeItem<String> uyItem1 = new TreeItem("y");
                                map.put(uyItem1, getrightPane1());
                                newLeaf.getChildren().addAll(uxItem1,uyItem1);
                                getTreeItem().getChildren().add(newLeaf);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (isEditing()) {
                    if (textField != null) {
                        textField.setText(item);
                    }
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(textField);
                } else {
                    setText(item);
                    setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
                    if (!(getTreeItem().isLeaf() && getTreeItem().getParent() == null)){
                        setContextMenu(menu);
                    }
                }           
            }
        }  
    }

    private static BorderPane getrightPane1() {              
        TextField textf1 = new TextField();
        TextField textf2 = new TextField();
        BorderPane root1 = new BorderPane(); 
        VBox vbox = new VBox(20);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));        
        HBox h1 = new HBox(7);
        HBox h2 = new HBox(7); 

        textf1.setPrefWidth(100);
        textf1.setPromptText("Enter Height");   
        textf1.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event)
            {  
                if(textf1.getText().length() > 0 && textf2.getText().length() > 0)
                {
                   Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle();
                    rect1.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textf1.getText()));
                    rect1.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textf2.getText()));
                    rect1.setFill(null);
                    rect1.setStroke(Color.RED);
                    root1.setCenter(rect1);
                }
            }
        });
        textf2.setPrefWidth(100);
        textf2.setPromptText("Enter Width");
        textf2.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event)
            {
                if(textf1.getText().length() > 0 && textf2.getText().length() > 0)
                {
                    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle();
                    rect2.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textf1.getText()));
                    rect2.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textf2.getText()));
                    rect2.setFill(null);
                    rect2.setStroke(Color.RED);
                    root1.setCenter(rect2);
                }
            }
        });

        if(textf1.getText().length() > 0 && textf2.getText().length() > 0 && root1.getCenter() == null)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
            rect.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textf1.getText()));
            rect.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textf2.getText()));
            rect.setFill(null);
            rect.setStroke(Color.RED);
            root1.setCenter(rect);
        }

        h1.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Y1:"), textf1);
        h2.getChildren().addAll(new Label("X1:"), textf2);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(h1, h2);        
        root1.setLeft(vbox);
        return root1;
    } 

    private static BorderPane getRootsPanel() { 
        BorderPane root2 = new BorderPane(); 
        HBox hbox = new HBox(10);
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(40));
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);

        List<BorderPane> listBordePane = new ArrayList(map.values());
        for(BorderPane element : listBordePane)
        {          
            Node node = element.getCenter();
            if(node instanceof Rectangle)
            {
                Rectangle rect1 = ((Rectangle)node);
                Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle();
                rect2.setWidth(rect1.getWidth());
                rect2.setHeight(rect1.getHeight());
                rect2.setFill(rect1.getFill());
                rect2.setStroke(rect1.getStroke());
                Platform.runLater(()->{hbox.getChildren().add(rect2);});               
            }
        }
        Platform.runLater(()->{root2.setLeft(hbox);});
        return root2;
    } 
}
```

TreeView where user can add roots and its coordinates. coordinates generates rectangles and rectangles are shown horizontally in root.

This is how code should work "**Every root should show all its coordinate's rectangles that are inside that `root` or inside its sub root.** " Simply saying if user has 2 roots, each should have its own coordinated rectangles, if both has sub roots that rectangles should be added.

due to this `if(TreeItem.getValue().equals("Roots"))`  i got all rectangles on every root that is wrong.  i tried this also `if(TreeItem == item1)` which is wrong.

I will be very thankful if you look at this problem of mine. thank you

Comment: Hi, I have just copied the code, so if I understand correctly when you click on a "Roots" item you would like to display all rectangles from its children inserted by the user. So for example Roots has 2 Coordinates children and If I insert 1 rectangle at first "Coordinates" and one at second then in Root should be displayed those 2 right?

Comment: @Sunflame, yes and if both has 2 more sub root with coordinates that rectangles should also be added on both

Comment: @Sunflame, as an exmaple let say there is father root, with 2 children roots. Each child root has 1 coordinate. so each child root will have 2 rectangles horizontally, so father root will have 4 rectangles. [just for understanding]

Comment: I think I know what you want, I am looking at your code, and I think it can be solved simply but there are many warnings and badly designed code fragment. So If you want to really work this, I suggest to think about it a little bit more. I can write you the whole code but I'm not sure about that helps you.

Comment: @Sunflame, Thank you so much, any help is way more better than having nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the code that works for me partially(in my opinion).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTreeCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main extends Application {

private static int rootNr = 0;
private static int coordinateNr = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

static final Map<TreeItem<String>, BorderPane> map = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    TreeItem<String> tree = new TreeItem<>("Main System");
    TreeItem<String> item1 = new TreeItem<>("Roots");
    TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(tree);
    treeView.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> {
        TreeItem<String> treeItem = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (treeItem.getChildren().stream().anyMatch(child -> child.getValue().startsWith("C"))) {
            root.setCenter(getRootsPanel(treeItem.getValue()));
        } else {
            root.setCenter(map.get(treeItem));
        }
    });

    treeView.setCellFactory(p -> new AddMenuTreeCell());
    tree.setExpanded(true);
    root.setLeft(treeView);
    tree.getChildren().add(item1);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 500);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Tree View");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private static class AddMenuTreeCell extends TextFieldTreeCell<String> {
    private ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();

    public AddMenuTreeCell() {
        MenuItem newitem1 = new MenuItem("Insert Roots");
        MenuItem newitem2 = new MenuItem("Insert Coordinates");
        menu.getItems().addAll(newitem1, newitem2);
        newitem1.setOnAction(arg0 -> {
            TreeItem<String> item3 = new TreeItem<>("Root" + rootNr++);
            getTreeItem().getChildren().add(item3);
        });
        newitem2.setOnAction(arg0 -> {
            TreeItem<String> newLeaf = new TreeItem<>("Coordinates" + coordinateNr++);
            TreeItem<String> uxItem1 = new TreeItem<>("X");
            map.put(uxItem1, getrightPane1());
            TreeItem<String> uyItem1 = new TreeItem<>("y");
            map.put(uyItem1, getrightPane1());
            newLeaf.getChildren().add(uxItem1);
            newLeaf.getChildren().add(uyItem1);
            getTreeItem().getChildren().add(newLeaf);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (!isEditing()) {
                setText(item);
                setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
                if (!(getTreeItem().isLeaf() && getTreeItem().getParent() == null)) {
                    setContextMenu(menu);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private static BorderPane getrightPane1() {
    TextField textf1 = new TextField();
    TextField textf2 = new TextField();
    BorderPane root1 = new BorderPane();
    VBox vbox = new VBox(20);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    HBox h1 = new HBox(7);
    HBox h2 = new HBox(7);

    textf1.setPrefWidth(100);
    textf1.setPromptText("Enter Height");
    textf1.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
        if (textf1.getText().length() > 0 && textf2.getText().length() > 0) {
            Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle();
            rect1.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textf1.getText()));
            rect1.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textf2.getText()));
            rect1.setFill(null);
            rect1.setStroke(Color.RED);
            root1.setCenter(rect1);
        }
    });
    textf2.setPrefWidth(100);
    textf2.setPromptText("Enter Width");
    textf2.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
        if (textf1.getText().length() > 0 && textf2.getText().length() > 0) {
            Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle();
            rect2.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textf1.getText()));
            rect2.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textf2.getText()));
            rect2.setFill(null);
            rect2.setStroke(Color.RED);
            root1.setCenter(rect2);
        }
    });

    if (textf1.getText().length() > 0 && textf2.getText().length() > 0 && root1.getCenter() == null) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textf1.getText()));
        rect.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textf2.getText()));
        rect.setFill(null);
        rect.setStroke(Color.RED);
        root1.setCenter(rect);
    }

    h1.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Y1:"), textf1);
    h2.getChildren().addAll(new Label("X1:"), textf2);
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(h1, h2);
    root1.setLeft(vbox);
    return root1;
}

private static BorderPane getRootsPanel(String root) {
    BorderPane root2 = new BorderPane();
    HBox hbox = new HBox(10);
    hbox.setPadding(new Insets(40));
    hbox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);

    for (Map.Entry<TreeItem<String>, BorderPane> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().getParent().getParent().getValue().equals(root)) {
            Rectangle rect1 = (Rectangle) entry.getValue().getCenter();
            if (rect1 != null) {
                Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle();
                rect2.setWidth(rect1.getWidth());
                rect2.setHeight(rect1.getHeight());
                rect2.setFill(rect1.getFill());
                rect2.setStroke(rect1.getStroke());
                Platform.runLater(() -> hbox.getChildren().add(rect2));
            }
        }
    }
    Platform.runLater(() -> root2.setLeft(hbox));
    return root2;
}
}
```

So your problem came here: You have to "remember" for every root which rectangles have in their children. So you have I put there some numbering to distinguish them, but it can be done without it. When you click on a root there will show its children's(which are coordinates) children's(which are X and Y) items. So now every Root displays the right rectangles.

There is a problem you should think about it:

- What if I have a Root that has 2 another Roots and those 2 roots have another 2-3 coordinates, then what should happen if I click on the main Root? There should be displayed all rectangles or nothing?

Comment: first of all thank you so much. You saved me there. Thanks. yes this works perfect. for the problem you mention "there should be displayed all rectangles". rectangles should be shown how do i approach with this where will be changes for this.